# Function returns null instead of expected value

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I call my function for a value that does not exist in the table:

```
SELECT pacjent_usun_PK_ERROR(5) from dual
```

*(PESEL='5' does not exist in my table)*

The function returns **NULL**.

But when I pass a valid value:

```
SELECT pacjent_usun_PK_ERROR(1) from dual
```

*(PESEL='1' exists in my table)*

The function returns **1**.

Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pacjent_usun_PK_ERROR
    ( PES IN NUMBER )
    RETURN NUMBER
IS
    ILE NUMBER;
    ZMIENNA NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT PACJENTID INTO ZMIENNA FROM PACJENT WHERE PESEL=PES;

    SELECT COUNT(PRZYJECIEID) INTO ILE FROM PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL
    WHERE  PACJENTID=ZMIENNA and rownum=1;

    RETURN ILE;
END;
```

When I test my last SELECT from my function, with manual inserted PRZYJECIEID
*(PACJENTID='1111' does not exist in my table)*

```
SELECT COUNT(PRZYJECIEID) FROM PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL WHERE PACJENTID='1111' and rownum=1;
```

Result is: **0**

and testing with PACJENTID='1' (exist in my table)

Result is: **1**

I am trying to understand why the function returns **NULL** instead of 0 when there are no rows.

I am using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Please tag appropriately. MySQL and Oracle are different, with different syntax.

Comment: I think I got it... (see the successive edits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what causes that behavior; if I can figure it out I will post again.

In any case, the following version should work. I created a similar function using the tables EMP and DEPT in the standard (Oracle) SCOTT schema, and the change I show below worked in that setting. Essentially I eliminate the intermediate variable; I do everything in a single query and assignment.

```
create or replace FUNCTION pacjent_usun_PK_ERROR
(PES IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  ILE NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(PRZYJECIEID) INTO ILE 
  FROM   PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL
  WHERE  PACJENTID=(SELECT PACJENTID FROM PACJENT WHERE PESEL=PES) 
     and rownum=1;
RETURN ILE;
end;
```

**Added**: To clarify... if `select into...` returns no rows, PL/SQL should raise an exception, specifically the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception. The mystery that is worth investigating is why PL/SQL does not raise this exception in this case.

**Final edit** - it appears this has always been the behavior in PL/SQL functions, as opposed to PL/SQL procedures. `NO_DATA_FOUND` is an exception (it can be handled in the usual manner) but **it is not raised**. See this old discussion on AskTOM: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:10321465390114

This means that when the first `select into` returns no data, the function is in an unhandled exception state. This is why the second `select into` doesn't result in a count of 0 - execution doesn't even get that far.

This also means that you may keep your function code exactly as it is, but you need to add an exception handling block:

```
exception
  when no_data_found then return 0;
```

right before `end;`

I tested this on my "mock-up" of your function (in the SCOTT schema) and it works.